# Ternary operator always evaluating to true part

Tags: javascript, ternary-operator

I have a statement:

```
var sep = '&nbsp;&nbsp;|&nbsp;&nbsp;';
var r = '';
for (var i = 0; i < menuItems.length; i++) {
    r += function(menuObject) {
    console.log(menuObject);
    console.log(
        '<a class="" href="' + 
        menuObject.url + '">' + menuObject.name + '</a>' + 
        (i < menuItems.length - 1) ? sep : ""); //logs the contents of sep
    ) //console.log expanded for readability
    }
}
```

Why is it not logging the full string, and instead only evaluating to `sep`?

Comment: you seem to have accepted an answer that looks wrong. Are you sure it does what you want it to do?

Comment: Technically the wording was correct, whereas the actual code sample was wrong.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because you are not wrapping your if line in parenthesis and it is process all of the string before it as the condition.

Try this...

```
var sep = '&nbsp;&nbsp;|&nbsp;&nbsp;';
        var r = '';
        for (var i=0;i<menuItems.length; i++) {
            r += function (menuObject) {
            console.log(menuObject);
            console.log(
                '<a class="" href="' + 
                menuObject.url + '">' + menuObject.name + '</a>'+ 
                ((i <menuItems.length-1 ) ? sep : "")); //logs the contents of sep
            }
       }
```

Answer (score 2):

The issue is operator precedence.

```
console.log(
            ('<a class="" href="' + 
            menuObject.url + '">' + menuObject.name + '</a>'+ 
            (i <menuItems.length-1 )) ? sep : "");
```

is being executed (mind the extra parenthesis I added). When using the ternary operator (which has only little to do with `if` clauses btw.) you should always use parenthesis like here:

```
console.log(
            '<a class="" href="' + 
            menuObject.url + '">' + menuObject.name + '</a>'+ 
            ((i <menuItems.length-1 ) ? sep : ""));
```

Answer (score 0):

Operator precedence. Put your expression before `?` in parentheses:

```
console.log(
        ('<a class="" href="' + 
        menuObject.url + '">' + menuObject.name + '</a>'+ 
        (i <menuItems.length-1 )) ? sep : "");
)
```

Comment: Uh, I don't think the `'<a class=""` is supposed to be part of the expression. You've just explicitly made it part of the expression.

Comment: -1 for incorrect evaluation, you are evaluating that the string is not null - will always be true